# ios in app purchase submit rejected

Tags: ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase, app-store

I uploaded my application to App Store which is written in Java(LibGDX Game framework), compiled/converted with Intel MOE. 
In application there is a store(uses Gdx-Pay 3rd party framework) which users can buy stars(which is consumable), and everything works fine with IAP system. 
Today they reviewed my application and said

> We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more
>   of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please be sure to take action and submit your
>   in-app purchases and upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more
>   about how to offer in-app purchases in iTunes Connect Developer Help.
>
> Once you've submitted your in-app purchases and uploaded a new binary,
>   we can proceed with your review.

I sent them store and purchasing images using TestFlight and result is :

> The IAPs are present in the app but need to be submitted in the binary
>   as Well for approval.

I am not sure what are they asking for, I created whole game with Java and can not change anything.

Comment: In iTunes connect you need to submit the iap for review

Comment: Your App needs to use StoreKit from iOS. You can't rely on 3rd party library for the shop. all revenue has to go thru Apple.